# Dozer- How to convert from simple class to abstract class with subclasses

Tags: java, converters, dozer

Here's the scenario, i have one class ADTO that has some properties that i want to convert with dozer to another type(A_DOMAIN) that is an abstract class with two subclasses, that hold the field as different enums:

```
public class A_DTO{
  private String field;
  private String fieldType;//should i use this with BeanFactory?
  privave String value;
  private CompareOperator operation;
}

public abstract class A_DOMAIN{

 private String value;
 private CompareOperator operation;
}

public class B_DOMAIN extends A_DOMAIN{

 private SearchFieldProc field;
}

public class C_DOMAIN extends A_DOMAIN{

 private SearchFieldDoc field;
}
```

So the idea is to convert from the class A_DTO to one of the subclasses of A_DOMAIN. The field property in the source class(A_DTO) holds the name() from enum so that i can convert to the enums SearchFieldProc and SearchFieldDoc in the subclasses.

My doubt here is if i should use the BeanFactory class to instantiate B_DOMAIN or C_DOMAIN depending of a string fieldType that will decide if i should instantiate B or C domain classes?Or can this be made with a custom converter?

Comment: Use interface to declare the functionality. User implementation classes as much as you want in number. Then use a factory class which will return the interface type (hiding the actual implementation object) .

Comment: the interface for which classes the destiny ones(B and C)?

Comment: Nevermind, so i use the interface instead of an abstract class for A_DOMAIN, but then do i use the factory class as the destiny one for the conversion?